# Qliksense: Compute median of grouped data

Tags: qliksense

I'm facing an issue in QlikSense, trying to compute some statistical indicators (Percentiles, Quartiles, StdDev, Median etc.) on a dataset which is already grouped by the source.

I mean that my dataset is something similar to the following, in which I have for each combination of Week and Customer Age the total number of purchases:
[image: Dataset]

I want to show the median of Customer Age, and due to the structure of the dataset I can't use fractile or median built-in functions, since they would come out with something different.

Let's suppose I want to calculate the median age of people for all the 3 weeks, so that I want to know what's the age of people who have done the 50% of my purchases.

To let you better understand the question, I show you the histogram:

[image: Histogram]

In this case, the median I want to get is 24-26 years, since the 50% of the total population falls under that range.

I found a useful reference here, but I am having troubles in writing this formula in QlikSense

https://mba-lectures.com/statistics/descriptive-statistics/603/relationship-between-quartiles-decile...

Thanks a lot in advance.

[EDIT]: This is my Data Model View:

[image: DMV]

[EDIT 2]: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Rr5YY7d4hUUklQdDhwOVJaTnNod0FDQi1jYkFpVlBibEVv/view?usp=drivesdk) is my qvf with a dataset more similar to the original one I'm using. As you can see, I can't get the correct result using your formula. In addition, I would like to use it in order to plot the trend of the median through weeks, but it doesn't seem to be possible (Even if I use the modified version of the formula I pointed out in the comments).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate median in such a scenario you need to weighted median and basically check which dimension value is in the middle:

```
Aggr(
    If(
        (Rangesum(
            Above([# Purchases],0,RowNo())
        )
        /Sum(TOTAL [# Purchases]))>=0.5 
    and 
        (Rangesum(
            Above([# Purchases],1,RowNo()-1))
        /Sum(TOTAL [# Purchases]))<0.5
    ,[Customer Age])
 ,[Customer Age])
```

Comment: Thanks Hubert. Unfortunately your script does not seem to work, returning a null value both in a table and in a KPI chart. It seems correct to me, but doesn't return the expected value.

Comment: Hi @FVerg I put my qvf file with example on my onedrive https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am4ZTQ8qcLwRs35Ms4wM8cEnIBxP

Comment: Ciao Hubert. Your qvf file works like a charm. If I try to replicate your formula on the dataset I showed in the first post, I don't get the same result. Putting the RangeSums in a table (With CustomerAge and # Purchases) it returns me a 0 for every row. I think that's the problem, but I don't get why it happens. Do you know why?

Comment: Please send screenshot of data model viewer so maybe I will figure out something.

Comment: Done. If I use Sum([# Purchases]) in the RangeSums it seems to be working, but I still don't get why.

Comment: I added my QVF to show how I would like to use the formula, and explained in [EDIT 2] why it's not working as expected. Thanks again in advance